# Расчет коэффициента корреляции Пирсона

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Есть два файла/фрейма. **Хочу сделать корреляцию**.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
data= pd.read_csv('close_prices.csv', header = None)
bata= pd.read_csv('djia_index.csv', header = None)
X = data.drop([0], axis =1)
X = X.drop([0], axis =0)
B = bata.drop([0], axis =1)
B = B.drop([0], axis =0)
pca = PCA(n_components=10)
pca.fit(X)
t = pca.transform(X)
dj=pca.transform(B)

c = np.corrcoef(t[:0], dj[:0])[0,1]

print (c)
```

Получаю:

```
----> c = np.corrcoef(t[:0], dj[:0])[0,1]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Comment: Каковы размерности “t” и “dj” ?

Comment: Они оба - числовые

t.shape 374*10

такого характера:

array([[-50.90240358,  17.63167724,   7.7360209 , ...,   3.55657041,
         -5.82197358,  -1.72604005],

dj.shape 374*10

такой:
array([[ 43305.26271674, -48792.50784745, -12341.49325408, ...,
        -23421.8388189 , -10739.03243356,    432.90196892],

я не понимаю смысл [0,1] в строке  ----> c = np.corrcoef(t[:0], dj[:0])[0,1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь посчитать корреляцию для двух **пустых** векторов:

```
In [78]: a = np.random.rand(374, 10) * 10

In [79]: a[:0]
Out[79]: array([], shape=(0, 10), dtype=float64)  # <--- матрица пуста !
```

Воспроизведение ошибки:

сначала создадим вторую матрицу которая линейно зависима от матрицы `a`:

```
In [81]: b = a * np.pi

In [82]: b.shape
Out[82]: (374, 10)
```

воспроизведение ошибки:

```
In [83]: c = np.corrcoef(a[:0], b[:0])

In [84]: c.shape
Out[84]: (0, 0)
```

далее вы пытаетесь обратиться ко второму (`index == 1`) элементу первой (`index == 0`) строки в 2D массиве (но наш массив - пустой):

```
In [85]: c[0,1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-cfb1d490a583> in <module>
----> 1 c[0,1]

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

---

Чтобы посчитать коэффициенты корреляции (по Пирсону) для двух матриц одинаковой размерности можно воспользоваться методом [DataFrame.corrwith(other, axis=0, drop=False, method='pearson')](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html).

По умолчанию корреляция будет расчитываться для столбцов с одинаковыми именами (параметр: `axis=0`), чтобы расчитать корреляцию по строкам с одинаковыми значениями индексов надо явно задать 
 параметр: `axis=1`

Пример:

```
In [86]: d1 = pd.DataFrame(a)

In [87]: d2 = pd.DataFrame(b)

In [88]: c = d1.corrwith(d2)

In [89]: c
Out[89]:
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
5    1.0
6    1.0
7    1.0
8    1.0
9    1.0
dtype: float64
```

теперь для проверки разрушим линейную зависимость для первого столбца:

```
In [91]: d2.iloc[:, 0] = np.random.rand(374)

In [92]: c = d1.corrwith(d2)

In [93]: c
Out[93]:
0    0.024225   # <--- NOTE !
1    1.000000
2    1.000000
3    1.000000
4    1.000000
5    1.000000
6    1.000000
7    1.000000
8    1.000000
9    1.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94119/discussion-between-maxu-and-eugene-venev).